# status 400 error on passing date to web service through ajax in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, date

Hi am working UI where i have to pass the form data from html page to server in json format through ajax order to insert the data inside the database well i have four fields namely
Project name:xxx
start date:DD:MM:YYY
end date:DD:MM:YY

### html file

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_name" 
name="project_name" 
data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4">

<div class="input-group date" id="start1">
<input data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-
control"name="start" id="start">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
 <div class="input-group date" id="end1">
<input data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-
control"name="start" id="end">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

### js for datepicker

```
$('#start1').datetimepicker({
    language:  'en',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  0,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
}); 
$('#end1').datetimepicker({
    language:  'en',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  0,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

### js and ajax to post data to database through url

```
var start_date=$("#start").val();
var end_date=$("#end").val();
var project=$("$project_name").val();
$.ajax({


url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify({
 projectName:projec_name,
 startDate:start_date,
  endDate:end_date,


  }),
 success: function (rtndata) {

         }
       }

 });
```

My issues is that am getting 400 status error as response from server only while passing date  to the controller.
and in spring boot controller it accepts json type data.

Comment: ES6 allows this @PredatorIWD

Answer (score 0):

hope I can help.

projectName:projec_name, is incorrect.
your variable is project only.
so it should be projectName:project,

Comment: sorry sir it the url given by the java developer in order to post value to the data base and Project_name got parsed where as start date and end data is not getting parsed instead the server responding with 400 status error